# Can pvlan-trunk Ports Carry normal vlans too on Juniper EX8208?

Tags: vlan, trunk, junos, private, pvlan

I'm trying to implement pvlan on Juniper EX8208 which will span across multiple switches (to a Cisco nexus 7000 Series) and need to know if the Inter-Switch-Link Port with "pvlan-trunk" will allow normal vlans too?